# Facebook CAPI PageView Event Missing Some Deduplication Parameters Parameter

Tags: php, facebook, events

I have two problems with Facebook CAPI. I'm using [facebook php business sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk)

### PageView Event Missing Some Deduplication Parameters Parameter

It's showing in every event in Event Manager (`PageView`, `ViewContent`, `Lead`) and I don't know why I haven't dedupi keys shown with CAPI in View Details, but It appears in Test mode. Example:

- [Event-Deduplication-View-Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5a1Q.png)
- [Test-Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9LoG.png)

Code:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['USERID']) || empty($_COOKIE['USERID'])){
    $externalId = FacebookCapiSettings::getExternalId();
    setcookie('USERID', $externalId, time()+14*24*3600);
    $_COOKIE['USERID'] = $externalId;
}

$access_token = FacebookCapiSettings::getAccessToken();
$pixel_id = FacebookCapiSettings::getPixelId();

$api = Api::init(null, null, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
$user_data = (new UserData())
// It is recommended to send Client IP and User Agent for Conversions API Events.
    ->setClientIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    ->setClientUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    ->setFbc($_COOKIE['_fbc'])
    ->setExternalId($_COOKIE['USERID'])
    ->setFbp($_COOKIE['_fbp']);

$eventSourceUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$event = (new Event())
    ->setEventName('PageView')
    ->setEventTime(time())
    ->setEventSourceUrl($eventSourceUrl)
    ->setUserData($user_data)
    ->setEventId(FacebookCapiPageView::getEventId())
    ->setActionSource(ActionSource::WEBSITE);

$events = array();
array_push($events, $event);

$request = (new EventRequest($pixel_id))
    ->setTestEventCode(FacebookCapiSettings::getTestKey())
    ->setEvents($events);
$response = $request->execute();
```

- Event ID as `setEventId(FacebookCapiPageView::getEventId())`
- External ID as `setExternalId($_COOKIE['USERID'])`
- FBP as `setFbp($_COOKIE['_fbp']);`

### Server Sending Invalid External ID Parameter.

It's showing only with `PageView` [Event Matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSfHV.png)

Code:

```
        <!-- Facebook Pixel -->
    <script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
        {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq( 'init', '<?php echo FacebookCapiSettings::getPixelId(); ?>', {'external_id': '<?php echo $_COOKIE['USERID']; ?>'<?php echo $userDataString; ?>} );
        fbq( 'track', 'PageView', {}, {eventID: '<?php echo FacebookCapiPageView::getEventId(); ?>'} );
    </script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                   src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<?php echo FacebookCapiSettings::getPixelId(); ?>&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript>
    <!--/ Facebook Pixel -->
```

---

What I did wrong and how I could repair my errors in Facebook Events Manager?

Comment: You asked 2 different questions there, please split them into 2 different questions.

Comment: @bitski if I have answer for my questions, should I still split them in two?